# Convert from drop shadow of PSD to box shadow of CSS3

Tags: css

I read this article http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/08/06/recreating-photoshop-drop-shadows-in-css3-and-compass/ many times. But I can't find the correct way to convert drop shadow of PSD to box shadow of CSS3 in this case:

```
Stroke: #E4E4E4; opacity 75%
Inner glow: #FFFFFF 50%; opacity 75%
Drop shadow:    Angle=90 degrees; distance=1px; spread=5%; size=9px
```

Answer (score 2):

```
border: 1px solid rgba(228,228,228,0.75);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.75), 0 1px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

I had to guess here a bit as there’s missing information. The `rgba(r,g,b,a)` colour syntax takes a value of 0–255 for each of the colour components and a 0–1 value for the opacity of the colour. So the `border` rule is equivalent to Photoshop stroke.

There’s no direct equivalent of an inner glow but you can do an inset box shadow which can simulate it. You specify multiple shadows with a comma on the same rule, so the first one can be the inset shadow. This is specified with an `inset` keyword to start with, then the x and y offset (none in this case), then a blur radius, then a spread distance, then finally the colour of the shadow. Play with the values; I guessed at 9px for the spread and 0 for the rest.

Finally, we specify a box shadow for the outside. The same rules apply as to the inset shadow (again with my guessing to the values). Have a play around!

Comment: Forgot to ask: what browser are you using? rgba() and box-shadow aren’t supported in IE8 and lower.

Answer (score -2):

There is a cloud based Photoshop extension that you can download and install in photo shop here: http://css3ps.com/. Then select a layer or layers which contain the drop shadow and click a button in toolbox then it will give you the css3 you need that matches the box shadow in the PSD. They have done the calculations for you.

I use it all the time for this question its great.

Comment: Can you add more to this post?